# Matplotlib Rectangle With Color Gradient Fill

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a rectangle, with a gradient color fill from left to right, at an arbitrary position with arbitrary dimensions in my axes instance (**ax1**) coordinate system.

[image]

My first thought was to create a path patch and somehow set its fill as a color gradient. But according to [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958835/matplotlib-color-gradient-in-patches) there isn't a way to do that.

Next I tried using a colorbar. I created a second axes instance **ax2** using `fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])` and added a color bar to that.

```
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, width, height/8])
colors = [grad_start_color, grad_end_color]
index  = [0.0, 1.0]
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', zip(index, colors))
colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cm, orientation='horizontal')
```

But the positional parameters passed to `fig.add_axes()` are in the coordinate system of **fig**, and don't match up with the coordinate system of **ax1**.

How can I do this?

Comment: I never use it but maybe this help you to recalculate coordinates from ax1 to fig: [Transformations Tutorial — Matplotlib 1.3.1 documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 9):

I have been asking myself a similar question and spent some time looking for the answer to find in the end that this can quite easily be done by [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.imshow([[0.,1.], [0.,1.]], 
  cmap = pyplot.cm.Greens, 
  interpolation = 'bicubic'
)
```

[image]

It is possible to specify a colormap, what interpolation to use and much more. One additional thing, I find very interesting, is the possibility to specify which part of the colormap to use. This is done by means of `vmin` and `vmax`:

```
pyplot.imshow([[64, 192], [64, 192]], 
  cmap = pyplot.cm.Greens, 
  interpolation = 'bicubic', 
  vmin = 0, vmax = 255
)
```

[image]

Inspired by [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html)

---

#### Additional Note:

I chose `X = [[0.,1.], [0.,1.]]` to make the gradient change from left to right. By setting the array to something like `X = [[0.,0.], [1.,1.]]`, you get a gradient from top to bottom. In general, it is possible to specify the colour for each corner where in `X = [[i00, i01],[i10, i11]]`, `i00`, `i01`, `i10` and `i11` specify colours for the upper-left, upper-right, lower-left and lower-right corners respectively. Increasing the size of `X` obviously allows to set colours for more specific points.

Comment: Yet another note: you might want to use the parameter `aspect = 'auto'` if you would like to set `xlim`/`ylim` in the future...

Answer (score 2):

did you ever solve this? I wanted the same thing and found the answer using the coordinate mapping from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862757/python-matplotlib-position-colorbar-in-data-coordinates),

```
 #Map axis to coordinate system
def maptodatacoords(ax, dat_coord):
    tr1 = ax.transData.transform(dat_coord)
    #create an inverse transversion from display to figure coordinates:
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    inv = fig.transFigure.inverted()
    tr2 = inv.transform(tr1)
    #left, bottom, width, height are obtained like this:
    datco = [tr2[0,0], tr2[0,1], tr2[1,0]-tr2[0,0],tr2[1,1]-tr2[0,1]]

    return datco

#Plot a new axis with a colorbar inside
def crect(ax,x,y,w,h,c,**kwargs):

    xa, ya, wa, ha = maptodatacoords(ax, [(x,y),(x+w,y+h)])
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    axnew = fig.add_axes([xa, ya, wa, ha])
    cp = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axnew, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Reds"),
                                   orientation='vertical',                                
                                   ticks=[],
                                   **kwargs)
    cp.outline.set_linewidth(0.)
    plt.sca(ax)
```

Hopefully this helps anyone in the future who needs similar functionality. I ended up using a grid of patch objects [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564273/matplotlib-continuous-colormap-fill-between-two-lines/29656697#29656697).